# Can clause normal form include true/false constants?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, conjunctive-normal-form

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) puts it,

> ... the only propositional connectives a formula in CNF can contain are and, or, and not. The not operator can only be used as part of a literal, which means that it can only precede a propositional variable or a predicate symbol.

But first-order logic also includes constant symbols `true` and `false`. Is it accurate to say that, as these are not variables, they must be eliminated before a formula can be considered valid CNF?

Answer (score 1):

A *clause* is a disjunction of literals.

Thus, if we have $\bot$ in it, we can apply the equivalence $l \lor \bot \equiv l$ to cancel $\bot$.

But we you can also retain it; in conclusion we are trying to reach the "empty clause" that is exactly $\bot$.

If we end with two clauses $\lnot l$ and $l \lor \bot$ the resolution procedure will produce $\bot$, i.e. exactly $\square$, showing that the set of clauses is *unsatisfiable*.

Comment: Indeed! On the other hand, in first-order logic with equality, we can also have literals like `a=a`, which can be simplified to `true`, but no one suggests leaving it at `a=a` makes it not valid CNF. So the fact that a simplification could be applied, is not by itself sufficient to establish that failure to apply it, would leave invalid CNF.